# Как вывести раннюю / позднюю дату?

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'TEST.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

ws1 = ws['B3':'B7']
for i in ws1:
    for cell in i:
    print (max(cell))
```

Есть определенный диапазон с датами в Excel файле. Мне нужно выбрать раннюю / позднюю дату. Пробовал различными способами, выдают разную ошибки. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибки у вас потому, что вы получаете не данные из ячеек, а кортеж-ссылку.
Кроме того, буквенно-цифровые индексы уже стараются не употреблять, поскольку openpyxl теперь старается работать с таблицей в канонической системе адресации (номер столбца: номер ряда).

Вот у меня для файла test.xls

```
         A
1    12.01.1976
2    05.02.1980
3    30.11.2018
4    03.07.2007
```

получается такое решение:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = wb.active

mycol=1 #номер столбца. A=1, B=2 и т.д
myrow = list(range(1,5)) # диапазон строк (1:4)
print(max(sheet.cell(row=x,column=mycol).value for x in myrow))
print(min(sheet.cell(row=x,column=mycol).value for x in myrow))
```

На выходе:

```
2018-11-30 00:00:00
1976-01-12 00:00:00
```

В общем, все работает, хотя, конечно, строки лучше бы перевести в `timestamp` и потом сравнивать.

Comment: Круто, работает. Можете объяснить зачем **data_only=True**?

Comment: @BenGoodman директива `data_only=True` как раз и говорит, что загружать нужно значения ячеек, а не референтные кортежи. Чтобы не было ошибки `builtins.AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value' `

Answer (score 2):

Вместо

```
for i in ws1:
    for cell in i:
        print (max(cell))
```

используйте

```
print(max([c.value for c in ws1]))
```

Comment: попробовал, выдает ошибку builtins.TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Cell' and 'Cell'

Comment: Вы прав - я исправил мой ответ.

Comment: теперь другая ошибка, builtins.AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'

Answer (score 2):

Модуль Pandas сильно упрощает и ускоряет работу с Excel файлами:

```
import pandas as pd   # pip install pandas

s = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Temp\files.xlsx', skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[1], squeeze=True)

print(s.min())
#2000-12-31 00:00:00

print(s.max())
#2018-11-30 00:00:00
```

Можно прочитать весь Excel файл в pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Temp\files.xlsx')
```

Comment: Я думал Pandas только читает данные. делает анализ и тд. Получается он может создавать, корректировать Excel файлы?

Comment: Pandas позволяет читать, писать, обрабатывать, анализировать и визуализировать данные из самых разных источников